# Use of the ternary operator: var ? 12-var : 0

Tags: c, operators, conditional-statements

Hey thank you very much for your time! I'm having trouble understanding the syntax of a statement in my audio coding textbook. In one example there is a print function that goes like this

```
printf("%d semitones up or %d semitones down\n", interval,
       interval ? 12-interval : 0 );
```

The part I don't understand is the conditional operator, or "?". It seems like I should just read it as "if interval does not equal 0, interval = 12 - interval" but the syntax here seems strange. I'm used to the conditional operator being a more fleshed out statement, like:

```
a = b > c ? b : c;
```

"If b is bigger than c, than a = b; else a = c"

Could someone point me to any other reference for this, or explain more about this syntax? I can't find similar examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost right, but there's no assignment taking place.  It's saying "if `interval` is non-zero, pass `12 - interval` to the `printf` statement, otherwise pass `0`".

In general the ternary operator looks like this:

```
  a ? b : c
```

Where `a`, `b`, and `c` are all expressions.  If `a` evaluates to non-zero, the ternary operator evaluates as if it were `b`, and if `a` evaluates to zero, the ternary operator's result is the result of evaluating `c`.

Your second example is a combination of the ternary operator and the assignment operator.  The ternary operator itself doesn't perform any assignments.

Answer (score -1):

Any expression that results in a boolean will do. In the case of C, where integers can be used as booleans, the value `0` is considered `false` and anything else is considered `true`.

So, in your case, `interval ? 12-interval : 0`, means: if `interval` is nonzero, use `12-interval`, otherwise, use `0`. To be extra verbose, you could rewrite it to:

```
 interval != 0 ? 12-interval : 0
```

Comment: `_Bool` (useable as `bool` via `stdbool.h`) has been part of standard C for almost 15 years.

Comment: My mistake. Never heard of it, never used it. Thanks for the info. I only had formal training using K&R, never did any formal C training after that. I updated my answer.